# Using UITextField across classes C# Xamarin

Tags: ios, xamarin

I am using the Viewcontroller
I have a `ViewController1.designer.cs` where I have registered a `UITextField`

```
[Outlet]
UIKit.UITextField getField { get; set; }
```

I have another class, `ViewController2` in which I use a method that needs

```
getField.text
```

Unfortunately, it is always null or empty even when the user has entered a value. How do I gain access to this UI element in a different class?

Note this is strictly for Xamarin.iOS and **not** Xamarin Forms.

Answer (score 0):

I assume ViewController2 is presented after ViewController1. If so why dont you pass the information you need from ViewController1 to ViewController2 when you are about to change a View?

At ViewController1 , pass data to the new view controller before presenting the new view:

```
ViewController2 nextVC = new ViewController2();
nextVC.dataFromVC1Field = getField.text;
// Presend view
```

and at ViewController2 , create a property to hold the data from text Field

```
public partial class ViewController : UIViewController
{
   public string dataFromVC1Field { get; set;}

   public override void ViewDidLoad ()
   {
       base.ViewDidLoad ();
   }
}
```